# Почему под Python 3.12 не ставится PyQT6?

Tags: python, pip, pyqt6, python-3.12

Под `Python 3.12` при попытке установить `PyQT6` вылезает ошибка.
Почему так может быть? 
Устанавливал `"Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`, пробовал отдельно ставить просто всякие `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater`, ошибка остается.

Полный лог установки:

```
PS C:\Users\ghost> pip install -U pyqt6
Collecting pyqt6
  Obtaining dependency information for pyqt6 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/83/b5f0d005bb7d5bae034edadcb62dc70f9a1c242ed49eb333850136dc0b5c/PyQt6-6.5.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  Using cached PyQt6-6.5.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting PyQt6-sip<14,>=13.4 (from pyqt6)
  Using cached PyQt6_sip-13.5.2.tar.gz (111 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting PyQt6-Qt6>=6.5.0 (from pyqt6)
  Obtaining dependency information for PyQt6-Qt6>=6.5.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/79/4a1683e57e9be1d9fa7e5fabe6ac6f485f63b01f07e6ae2f45fa94ed1420/PyQt6_Qt6-6.5.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  Using cached PyQt6_Qt6-6.5.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (551 bytes)
Using cached PyQt6-6.5.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (6.5 MB)
Using cached PyQt6_Qt6-6.5.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (59.3 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyQt6-sip
  Building wheel for PyQt6-sip (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for PyQt6-sip (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'PyQt6.sip' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyQt6-sip
Failed to build PyQt6-sip
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyQt6-sip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

PS Воткнул из интереса `Python 3.11.6`, в него все ставится без проблем...

Comment: Много последнее время эта ошибка у кого вылезает, и не только на двенадцатом питоне... У меня pyqt на девятом с этой же ошибкой не ставится.

Comment: @Глеб мдя... а я тут воткнул из интереса Python 3.11.6, в него все ставится без проблем...

Comment: Интересно. Видимо pyqt как-то недообновился, двенадцатую версию же недавно выпустили.

Comment: Попробуй обновить всякие там `wheel`, `setuptools`, `pyproject.toml`. Некоторым помогает.

Comment: Нужно или попробовать установить компилятор C++, или ждать когда выкатят PyQt6 с прекомпилированными wheels для Python 3.12. Вообще, не стоит пока спешить с переходом на 3.12, лучше подождать где-то с полгода, пока основные библиотеки обновят.

Comment: @Глеб уже, уже. не помогло.

Comment: @insolor это та фигня, которая "visual-cpp-build-tools"? Так поставил, не помогло. Ясненько, значит сижу на 3.11.6